# Is there a way to get permalink url for Facebook video from source link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have several link for Facebook video:

```
https://video-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/14777382_352549381750282_5319998628880711680_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjNfNDI2X2NyZl8yM19tYWluXzMuMF9mcmFnXzJfdmlkZW8ifQ%3D%3D&oh=4176d4af7b2bdb9c1a576788deccc60e&oe=581A2C50&bytestart=0&byteend=986

https://video-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/14957324_1230377787018990_3376439516993683456_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjNfNDI2X2NyZl8yM19tYWluXzMuMF9mcmFnXzJfdmlkZW8ifQ%3D%3D&oh=4141d2d27f11a908318285b70897d63a&oe=581A0839&bytestart=0&byteend=967

https://video-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/14780373_352549378416949_5640459543428202496_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjNfNDI2X2NyZl8yM19tYWluXzMuMF9mcmFnXzJfYXVkaW8ifQ%3D%3D&oh=5de810564f6abb1fe5ae7200dd230da4&oe=581A3ACE&bytestart=49582&byteend=61578
```

Is there a way to somehow find out that all they belongs to one video: https://www.facebook.com/319028891768998/videos/352548755083678/ ?

Yeah, I can get source link from video id by Graph API like that

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=352548755083678%2F%3Ffields%3Dsource&version=v2.8
```

But can I somehow invert this operation?

Comment: There is not. Also the CDN urls are temporary

Comment: @WizKid *&%! I put a link on a page and it worked for quite a while but I went back and checked, and sure enough, it's broken! :'-(